# Locus of fixed points of an involution in a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, minimal-surfaces, involutions

I am reading Guletskii Paper "Bloch Conjecture for surfaces with involution and of p_g=0" and I do not know why the following is true.

If S is a minimal smooth projective surface with an involution i. Why the locus of fixed points of the involution i is either

1) a smooth curve (possibly reducible) and a finite collection of points, or

2) empty.

Maybe someone can give  any advice about it :).

Comment: The sentence beginning "If S is a smooth projective surface..." seems to be missing a word after minimal (if not, what does minimal refer to?). You may also wish to avail yourself of [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to help format your post. Finally, is this surface assumed to be over $\Bbb C$ or over a more general field? Skimming the paper, it seems the author switches between contexts with some freedom, and I don't see the exact statement from your post.

Comment: Dear KReiser sorry for my mess. A minimal surface is when it does not contain a (-1)-curve.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying - I still would really recommend formatting your post with MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of a more general statement. For a finite order automorphism of a complex manifold the fixed point set is a collection of complex sub-manifolds (of possibly different dimensions).  Firstly choose a $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$-invariant Hermitian metric on $X$, just by choosing any Hermitian metric and by averaging.

Now, consider a fixed point $p$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ acts complex linearly on $T_{p}X$. The fixed point set of this representation is the Eigenspace for the Eigenvalue $1$, hence a complex subspace $V \subset T_{p}X$.

Then by considering the exponential map of the corresponding Riemannian metric, which is equivariant since the metric is invariant. The image of $V$ is precisely the fixed point set (in some neighbourhood of $p$), hence it is a complex submanifold.

Note that if the original complex manifold was a projective variety then the components of the fixed point set are smooth subvarieties by Chow's theorem.

Note that the fixed point set does not necessarily have to contain a curve i.e. the fixed point set can be just a finite collection of points. Consider the minimal surface $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^{1}$ with the involution $$([a_{1},a_{2}],[b_{1},b_{2}]) \mapsto ([-a_{1},a_{2}],[-b_{1},b_{2}]) .$$ Note that this involution has $4$ fixed points.

Comment: Thank you Nick L!

Comment: Dear Nick L, you help me a lot thanks!!!... Maybe you could give me the reference where you learned all this things (about fixed set of involutions :)  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I learnt this in a slightly different context. In fact, this result holds in many different categories smooth, symplectic, almost complex, complex, etc... It is a well known argument but I don't know a place where the complex case is written explicitly.